# My visualvm just shows Glassfish and netbeans not some of my opend projects in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler, visualvm

Following visualvm [documentation](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) , I've tried to set userdir parameter of visual vm, but none of the following works.

**Command**

```
c:\Users\Jack\visualvm_136\visualvm_136\bin\visualvm.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11" --userdir "...."
```

**Addresses that I've used for userdir parameter**

```
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\J2EE\TargetModules\_C__Program_File-1649106768\GlassFish_Server-1221303575

C:\Temp

C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository

C:\Users\Jack\Recent

C:\Users\Jack\Projects
```

Comment: You will need to specify what is the expected outcome. Also, what kind of applications you are starting from NB. Otherwise it is absolutely impossible to provide any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the versions and re-install the plugin of VM on netbeans. it seems they do not refer to the same version.